# Error on PHP fgets() reading a line of CSV

Tags: php

I am working on this snippet. Why am I getting `fgets()` error on line 6?

> Warning: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in
>   D:\wamp64\www\WP\wp-content\plugins\test.php on line 6

Code:

```
<?php
$file = "http://localhost:8080/WP/Data.csv";
function wdm_validate_csv($csv_file)
{
    $requiredHeaders = array('title', 'price','color');
    $firstLine = fgets($csv_file); //get first line of the CSV file
    $fileHeader = str_getcsv(trim($firstLine), ',', "'"); //parse the contents to an array

    //check the headers of the file
    if ($foundHeaders !== $requiredHeaders) {
      // report an error
      return false;
    }

    return true;
}
wdm_validate_csv($file);
```

As you can see I have a CSV file at this `$file = "http://localhost:8080/WP/Data.csv"` directory and trying to read it

Comment: You must create a resource handle with `fopen()`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, `fgets` requires a `resource`, not a `string`. Try using `file_get_contents` instead:

```
<?php
$file = "http://localhost:8080/WP/Data.csv";
function wdm_validate_csv($csv_file)
{
    $requiredHeaders = array('title', 'price','color');
    $firstLine = file_get_contents($csv_file); //get first line of the CSV file
    $data = str_getcsv(trim($firstLine), ',', "'"); //parse the contents to an array
    $foundHeaders = array_key_exists($data[0]) ? $data[0] : null;

    //check the headers of the file
    if ($foundHeaders !== $requiredHeaders) {
      // report an error
      return false;
    }

    return true;
}
wdm_validate_csv($file);
```

Comment: Thanks steadweb but I am getting two errors now `Undefined variable: foundHeaders in D:\wamp64\www\WP\wp-content\plugins\test.php on line 10` and  `Warning: file_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, resource given in D:\wamp64\www\WP\wp-content\plugins\test.php on line 6`

Comment: `$foundHeaders` isn't declared within the mentioned code :) - that needs defining. Are you passing `$file` through to the `wdm_validate_csv` function? `$file` is a string, so this should work.

Comment: Your `$firstLine` is not the first line, it's the entire contents

Comment: You are right Andreas, I am actually getting entire text!

Answer (score 0):

if you read a file with Url you can use the function file_get_contents(), but if you need to read in the local server change this http://localhost:8080/WP/Data.csv for "./WP/Data.csv" if the php file is in the root directory.

`

```
<?php
    // Create a stream
    $opts = array(
        'http'=>array(
        'method'=>"GET",
        'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
        "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
        )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);

    // Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
    $file = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/', false, $context);
?>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Using `file()[0]` will give you the first line of a file.
`file()` returns a file as an array line by line, and `[0]` means give me the first line only.
Then I assume it's a typo `$fileheaders` and `$foundheaders`?

```
$file = "http://localhost:8080/WP/Data.csv";
function wdm_validate_csv($csv_file)
{
    $requiredHeaders = array('title', 'price','color');
    $firstLine = file($csv_file)[0]; //get first line of the CSV file
    $fileHeader = str_getcsv(trim($firstLine), ',', "'"); //parse the contents to an array

    //check the headers of the file
    if ($fileHeader !== $requiredHeaders) {
      // report an error
      return false;
    }

    return true;
}
wdm_validate_csv($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're going to do other stuff with the file after validating its headers, I think it makes sense to open it and pass the resource handle to the function instead of just the path.

```
$file = fopen("http://localhost:8080/WP/Data.csv");
$valid_headers = wdm_validate_csv($file);
```

If your CSV is valid, you can combine `fgets` and `str_getcsv` into one operation with [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

```
function wdm_validate_csv($csv_file)
{
    $requiredHeaders = array('title', 'price','color');
    $fileHeader = fgetcsv($csv_file); //get first line of the CSV file
    return $fileHeader == $requiredHeaders;
}
```

`file_get_contents` and `file` are great, but they're both going to read the entire file in, which is a bit heavy if you just need to check the first line.